# which side of the expression gets evaluated first?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

Will the right side of the expression get evaluated first or the left ?

```
void main ()
{
    int i = 0 , a[3] ;
    a[i] = i++;
    printf ("%d",a[i]) ;
}
```

Comment: Oh! SO got so many questions of this type...

Comment: @Nyan:  It's a common pitfall.

Comment: @Nyan : Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457967/what-belongs-in-an-educational-tool-to-demonstrate-the-unwarranted-assumptions-pe/3458842#3458842) answer.

Comment: So common that it's in c-faq...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The order of evaluation of the operands of the assignment operator is unspecified:  the operands may be evaluated in any order.

However, this expression (`a[i] = i++`) yields undefined behavior because you both modify `i` (using `i++`) and you separately read `i` (using `a[i]`) without a sequence point in between those actions.

Comment: @msakr, i would be incremented at the end if there was something like a[k] = i++ ;. As James McNellis said, it's undefined behavior for a[i] = i++; due to no sequence points between the actions.

Comment: @msakr: C standard §6.5/2: "Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value
shall be read only to determine the value to be stored."

Comment: @msakr:  Concerning the order of evaluation, see C99 Appendix J ("Unspecified Behavior"):  "The order in which subexpressions are evaluated and the order in which side effects take place, except as specified for the function-call `()`, `&&`, `||`, `?:`, and comma operators."  Jonathan gives the quote that states that this particular expression yields undefined behavior.

Comment: @msakr: The source would be the list of sequence points as given in the C standard.

Comment: @James : ` ...because you both modify i (using i++) and you read i (using a[i]) without a sequence point...`. The expression `b += a += b` does not invoke UB even though `b` is being read and modified without a sequence point. `a[i] = i++` invokes UB because the `prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored` rule is violated. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Prasoon:  That is correct.  Jonathan in a comment to this answer and sysenter in his answer both quote that part of the standard.

Answer (score 3):

C does not define which side gets evaluated first. The standard states (C99 §6.5/2):

> Between the previous and next sequence
>   point an object shall have its stored
>   value modified at most once by the
>   evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be
>   accessed only to determine the value
>   to be stored

The aforementioned result you posted is thereby UB.