# Is inserting map size as value into a map undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, sequence-points, unspecified-behavior

edit: **this question should have not been closed**, if you look at the answers you will see they are totally different(old question has no mention of C++17).

I was reading a PVS [blog](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0629/) post where they mention the following bug.

(reduced)

```
std::map<int,int> m;
m[7]=5;
auto val = 15;
if (!m.contains(val)){
    m[val] = m.size(); // bug here
}
```

According to blog post this is buggy.
I always thought that operator [] call for map is a function call so .size() is sequenced before [] because functions act as sequence point.

So why is this a bug?

note: I know sequence points do not exist since C++11, but I use them since new wording is much harder for me to understand.

Comment: In the link provided by @cigien [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18040079/2296458) splits the hair regarding sequence points.

Comment: This strikes me as a mistake in the PVS blog post. The sequencing might be unspecified, but that's different from UB.

Comment: _"I always thought that operator [] call for map is a function call so .size() is sequenced before [] because functions act as sequence point"_ Assignment of ints doesn't though

Comment: regarding comments: this is what blog says :
You just don't know if the size function will be called before or after adding the new element.

@cigien I have read the linked answer and it does not explain my problem.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I think you answer my question... feel free to make it an answer...

Comment: The behavior of this has changed recently.  Before C++17 this was unspecified behavior.  In C++17  left hand side is guaranteed to be sequenced before the right hand side making it defined bebhavior.  I left a comment on the possible dupe target asking the accepted answer to update so it would be complete for you.

Comment: @s3cur3 if `m[val]` and `m.size()` would be indeterminately sequenced then you would be right. But they are unsequenced and it's UB

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Sorry, I had the behavior reversed.  The second and third sentences [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ass#1) say right happens before left, so 1 is the expected behavior.

Comment: I am happy to see so many close votes on a question where I actually learned something new(IDK that = is a sequence point in C++17)...  \s
I may be biased since it is my question, but I feel SO is too trigger happy wrt close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pre C++17

> § 1.9 Program execution [intro.execution] (n3690 c++14 draft)
>
> 15. Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are
>       unsequenced.

and 5.17 [expr.ass] doesn't mention any sequencing between the operands of built-in assignment. So the evaluation of the two operands of the built-in assignment operator `=` is unsequenced with regards to each other.

`m[val]` and `m.size()` can be evaluated in any order (can even overlap - interleaved the CPU instructions).

Considering:

- `m[val]` has a side effect of modifying the map's size (a scalar)
- the value computation of `m.size()` accesses the map's size

> § 1.9 Program execution [intro.execution] (n3690 c++14 draft)
>
> 15. [...] If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either [...] or a value computation using the value of the same
>       scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

So yes, the behavior is indeed Undefined.

## C++17

> §8.5.18 Assignment and compound assignment operators [expr.ass] (n4713
>   C++17 draft)
>
> 1. The assignment operator (=) [...] The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.

So the behavior is defined. `m.size()` will be evaluated before `m[val]`

Comment: I am talking about `m.size()` from `m[val] = m.size()`

Comment: yes, my mistake... btw gcc changed behavior from 6.4 to 7.1 https://godbolt.org/z/LHU9X3