# Question about how assignment operator work

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code:

```
stack = [1, 2, 3]
lst = [[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]      # Just a 5x5 2D list of 0
```

The following assignment didn't behave like I expected
`lst[stack.pop()][stack.pop()] = stack.pop()`
I thought the above would be `lst[3][2] = 1`. Turn out it's `lst[2][1] = 3`
I kinda have a vague idea why, but I do want to know more about this behavior. Can you guys point me to any doc or article about this?

Comment: @ggorlen: No. That's about something completely different.

Comment: This is a question about `pop`, not item assignment.

Comment: See this. I believe the right side is evaluated before the left side. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753335/is-python-assignment-strictly-evaluated-right-to-left

Comment: @DanielWalker It's somewhat relevant, as you need to know the order in which the `pop` methods are called, and the assignment syntax determines that.

Comment: @chepner, that's a fair point.

Comment: Stack has only 3 objects in it, and in python, the first index is 0, second is 1, and third is 2.

Comment: @AnnZen, `pop()` pops items from the end of the list and returns it. So it will return the value at index `2` first.

Comment: @Sri what makes you think i don't know?

Comment: @Sri, thanks. I yeah I thought it had something with order of evaluation. I just want to know more

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with the execution order of expressions. The right side gets evaluated first, and then the two other ones from left to right. The right side usually gets evaluated first in almost all programming languages.

The relevant section of the Python documentation is here: [Python Reference Assignment Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). Stated there is:

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that
>   this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter
>   yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of
>   the target lists, from left to right.

Based on this definition of assignment statements:

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (starred_expression | yield_expression)
target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
target          ::=  identifier
                     | "(" [target_list] ")"
                     | "[" [target_list] "]"
                     | attributeref
                     | subscription
                     | slicing
                     | "*" target
```

There are more rules at play that really define the execution order, but that gets deep into the specification and into technical details how the language works in every possible situation. But above is the answer to your specific question.

Comment: Just throwing this link here if someone want's to read more on evaluation order. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

Comment: @Sri Nice, there is the simpler version of my answer in one sentence :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what the disassembler can tell us:

```
>>> dis.dis('lst[stack.pop()][stack.pop()] = stack.pop()')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (stack)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (pop)
              4 CALL_METHOD              0
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (lst)
              8 LOAD_NAME                0 (stack)
             10 LOAD_METHOD              1 (pop)
             12 CALL_METHOD              0
             14 BINARY_SUBSCR
             16 LOAD_NAME                0 (stack)
             18 LOAD_METHOD              1 (pop)
             20 CALL_METHOD              0
             22 STORE_SUBSCR
             24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

The assignment operation is broken down like this:

```
lst[b][c] = a
```

In terms of methods being called, this is equivalent to

```
lst.__getitem__(b).__setitem__(c, a)
```

(with the call to `__getitem__` used by `BINARY_SUBSCR` and the call to `__setitem__` by `STORE_SUBSCR`).

Although it would see that `b` should have been evaluated first, assignments are always executed by evaluating the right-hand side first, then the left-hand side, so the real execution is closer to

```
t1 = a
t2 = lst.__getitem__(b)
t2.__setitem__(c, t1)
```